# LinkButton Postback In Repeater In Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The code is a little big to post here, but hopefully someone can give me some ideas on what to look for.

I've got an ASP.NET Webforms page, containing a Bootstrap Modal dialog box. Inside this modal I have some `runat="server"` controls, including a `Repeater`. I have 2 `LinkButton` controls, one inside the `Repeater` and one outside, both of which are bound to the same server-side event handler.

The link outside the `Repeater` works correctly. The one inside still posts-back, but does not fire the event as expected.

Some things I noticed:

1. My first thought was that the modal was being removed from the
   ASP.NET form (as some are prone to do), but if this was true, none
   of the controls inside would work.
2. I tried this using regular Buttons, and it worked correctly. That
   means it's something to do with the `__doPostBack` Javascript that
   LinkButtons use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, are you say that LinkButton in Repeater cause full post-back?
 are you try to set ClientIDMode="AutoID" for repeater?
What do you mean *"but does not fire the event as expected"*

Comment: The LinkButton in the Repeater is doing a full post-back, I can see the Page_Load method being called. The actual button-click event handler method does not get called though.

Comment: Calling Page_Load in every postback is usual even when you using UpdatePanels, It's not a problem, you can handle it using Page.IsPostBack.
When i say a full postback, i mean a whole refresh. Is this your problem? did you try ClientIDMode="AutoID" for repeater?
And for button click handler, do you have any JQuery code associated with this button? something like $("#LinkButton1").click() {... ?